# How to write a value in json file using if conditions in powershell?

Tags: json, powershell

I am trying to add value in key pair json file using Powershell. I am getting an error. Need some guidance on PS Scripting.

Powershell 5.1 version and json file with key pair inside it.

MYJSON File:

```
  {   "Theme":{"Res_List":  {
                    "Method":  "POST",
                     "Name":""}}}
```

PowerShell Script:

```bsh
$file_path="C:\Users\RelativeConfig.json"

$json = Get-Content $file_path | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json

$timestamp = Get-Date -Format ddMMHHmm

$namevalue = 'resource'+$timestamp+'e3'
echo $namevalue ##prints resource16sep2019 I want this to write in json as value for Name Key
$files = $json | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | Select-Object - ExpandProperty Name

$result = Foreach ($file in $json)
{
    if ($file.Name -eq "Name") { $file.Value = $namevalue}
}
$result | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $json
```

Error:

No error but json is not updated with new values.

Expected:

```
{   "Theme":{"Res_List":  {
                    "Method":  "POST",
                     "Name":"resource16sep2019 "}}}
```

Actual:

```
  {   "Theme":{"Res_List":  {
                    "Method":  "POST",
                     "Name":""}}}
```

Comment: you also want to update the json file?

Comment: yes my task was to update the json file with the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update your value in json you can do something like below

```
$bucket_name = "resource16sep2019"    ## I want this to write in json as value for Name Key

$json.Theme.Res_List.Name = $bucket_name
```

It will directly replace the `$bucket_name` value with the `Name` value in JSON.

If you want to write this to the respective file use the below command,

```
$json | ConvertTo-Json -depth 32| set-content $file_path
```

Hope it helps! Cheers

Comment: it is not updating json file.

Comment: Thanks! but What happens is it replaces the complete json and writes only the name in json file. I need to use if condition to check if row.key -eq "Name" then add output in value. I am trying many options but in vain.

Comment: It doesn't replace the complete JSON in your file. It will replace as "{   "Theme":{"Res_List":  {
                    "Method":  "POST",
                     "Name":"resource16sep2019 "}}}"

Comment: No ng-suhas, it is replacing completely,I am trying other options as well.Thanks!